# How to select the 2 newest entries in a SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am fairly new to sql and i dont have much knowledge on the subject yet and I have a problem. I was trying to select data from my database tables using this query:

```
SELECT 
Distinct
    UPPER(M.name) AS 'Member Name',
    M.memberID AS 'Member ID',
    (b.bookTitle + ' / ' + a.firstName + ' ' + a.lastName) AS 'Title',
    l.barCode AS 'barcode',
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), lr.dueDate, 5) + ' Renewed ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), 
    (SELECT COUNT(lr.LoanID)
     FROM Loan l, LoanRenewal lr
     WHERE lr.LoanID = l.loanID
       AND l.memberID = 's002')) + ' times') AS 'Status',
    bc.callNumber AS 'Call Number'
FROM 
    Book b,
    Author a,
    BookAuthor ba,
    bookCopy bc,
    Member M,
    MemberType mt,
    Loan l,
    LoanRenewal lr,
    PublishWork pw
WHERE 
    M.memberID = 's002'
    AND M.memberID = l.memberID
    AND l.loanID = lr.LoanID
    AND l.barCode = bc.barCode
    AND bc.ISBN = pw.ISBN
    AND pw.BookId = b.BookID
    AND ba.BookID = b.BookID
    AND b.Main_AuthorID = a.authorID
```

When I run this, the result it returns is this

```
Member Name | Member ID | Title                        | barcode | Status                  | Call Number |
LIM HAI MEI | S002      | Developing an App / Ben Grimm| 1234567 | 20-02-16 Renewed 4 times|TK5105.887 Kar|
LIM HAI MEI | S002      | Java 101 / Yee Chak Thong    | abcdefg | 20-02-16 Renewed 4 times|TK5105.886 Kar|
LIM HAI MEI | S002      | Java 101 / Yee Chak Thong    | abcdefg | 25-02-16 Renewed 4 times|TK5105.886 Kar|
LIM HAI MEI | S002      | Java 101 / Yee Chak Thong    | abcdefg | 28-02-16 Renewed 4 times|TK5105.886 Kar|
```

But what I want it to return is this as I just want the recent records and also how to dynamically isolate the data

```
 Member Name | Member ID | Title                        | barcode | Status                  | Call Number |
LIM HAI MEI | S002      | Developing an App / Ben Grimm| 1234567 | 20-02-16 Renewed 1 times|TK5105.887 Kar|
LIM HAI MEI | S002      | Java 101 / Yee Chak Thong    | abcdefg | 28-02-16 Renewed 4 times|TK5105.886 Kar|
```

Please help me with this i could not find a suitable code that is dynamic and not in anyway hardcoding

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "newest"?

Comment: I cant really explain but you can say i want to find the newest in terms of date in the status  but also distinct between the 2 different titles if you have a better name for the title please tell me

Comment: I advice you to learn modern explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: My GROUP BY? I can't see any aggregate functions there...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Sorry i would edit it to use distinct but somehow i cannot edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Group By & Aggregation on column Status(Max is the recent one)

```
    SELECT [MEMBER NAME],[MEMBER ID],[TITLE],[BARCODE],MAX(STATUS),[CALL NUMBER]
    FROM (

    --YOUR CODE MENTIONED IN QUESTION

    )AS A
    GROUP BY [MEMBER NAME],[MEMBER ID],[TITLE],[BARCODE],[CALL NUMBER]
```

Comment: wait this work 
Why does this work i don't understand

Comment: This will work because I am grouping all similar columns with group by and making it distinct record as per your requirement i.e Recent dated (MAX)

Comment: SELECT Title, COUNT(Title) FROM (
        ---YOUR CODE MENTIONED IN QUESTION

 ) AS A
  GROUP BY Title

Answer (score 1):

This depends on having a field by which you can rank newness, which I can't see in your query above. Assuming you have though, what you want is to use the ROW_NUMBER function like this -

```
SELECT
    <FieldList>
FROM
    (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Newness DESC) Ix,
        <FieldList>
    FROM
        <Tables>) x
WHERE
    Ix <=2
```